# Most efficient way to count distinct values and return it as an object

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I wanted to build an aggregation in MongoDB that would count the amount of occurences of distinct values that occur within a certain field among a whole collection and return this as one object consisting out of keys that represent all distinct values containing the amount of occurences among the collection as value.

Say you have collection of players, each player belongs to a certain team. Something like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "John Doe",
        team: "Blue"
    },
    {
        name: "Eric Doe",
        team: "Blue"
    },
    {
        name: "Diana Doe",
        team: "Blue"
    },
    {
        name: "Jane Doe",
        team: "Red"
    },
    {
        name: "Jennifer Doe",
        team: "Red"
    },
    ...
]
```

And what you need to end up with is the following:

```
    {
        blue: 3,
        red: 2,
        ...
    }
```

Now I have the following aggregation:

```
[
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$team', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$team', 
            'count': {
                '$sum': 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': null, 
            'root': {
                '$push': {
                    'k': '$_id', 
                    'v': '$count'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': {
                '$arrayToObject': '$root'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And it does the job it has to do, my question is though, does it do it's job well? Or could it be more efficient?

Comment: why are you using `$unwind` stage? as per your data its not needed.

Comment: @turivishal that would only be beneficial when team could be an array containing multiple teams right?

Comment: okay, i don't see any other improvement points, this is the actual way to do this task, are you facing any issue in this query?

Comment: @turivishal no, my question was just if this was the most efficient way to do this and if you basically say you don't see any improvements points other than the unwind being uncecessary if team would always contain a single value then that basically answers my question. I just thought that maybe someone would say that you could combine the latter 3 to one group aggregation but I guess that is not possible, is it?

Comment: I can't say it is an efficient way, it depends on your collection data, the requirement of feature, but i can say this is the better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `$map` and `$setUnion` to achieve this:

We arrive with an array of objects with `k` and `v`. Second stage converts it to a single object.

```
[{
    '$project': {
        'teams': {
            '$map': {
                'input': {
                    '$setUnion': '$data.team'
                }, 
                'as': 'a', 
                'in': {
                    'k': '$$a', 
                    'v': {
                        '$size': {
                            '$filter': {
                                'input': '$data', 
                                'cond': {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$$a', '$$this.team'
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'final': {
            '$arrayToObject': '$teams'
        }
    }
}]
```

You may find more info regarding this [here](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-group-an-array-using-reduce-without-unwind-group/8550)